# Premature end of POST data - Ajax with FormData is Broken on IE10 / IE11 in Some Conditions

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a JSP application.

Wherein a set of data will be sent to an JSP using AJAX request.

The issue is, I am getting an error when a data is sent to the JSP in Internet Explorer 11. Whereas it properly works in IE9.

```
IllegalStateException - IOException: Premature end of POST data
```

I couldn't find answers in google, as well as i couldn't reveal the code as its proprietary.

### Request Class:

```
request     EvermindHttpServletRequest

response        EvermindHttpServletResponse

pageContext     EvermindPageContext

session     EvermindHttpSession
```

Comment: **Intercept the data,** maybe with TamperData plugin in FireFox. Maybe it is a broken UTF-8 encoding, JSON syntax error caused by data, JavaScript error.

Comment: @JoopEggen I am using jDeveloper 10g IDE for developing the app, where we could intercept the data. The error is just shown as "IllegalStateException - IOException: Premature end of POST data" There is not even stack trace.

Comment: So you have something which is sending a broken HTTP request. What is this "something". Some javascript doing an Ajax post request? If so, what does that javascript look like? And PS: you can see in the browser the HTTP request being sent, IE11 will have a development console too which should also have a HTTP logging facility.

Comment: Do the post data not originate from the browser? Then the partial data may be inspected to get an idea what exactly might be the cause.